# Console continues to output the string wrapped as an Optional in Swift, why?

Tags: swift, option-type

Please help, I am really struggling with this, have read multiple threads and tuts on this but can't seem to find the issue. I have applied the same approach as another block of code on my app.

I am setting `var` `dictionary` with a value when I instantiate the `ViewController` from a source `ViewController`.

But the console continues to output the string wrapped as an Optional and therefore also on the UI, why?

```
sender.name: Liam, 01/13/1990, Optional("Actor")
```

Setting `dictionary` with a value:

```
var dictionary: [String : Any]!{

    didSet{
        print("inside InviteVC")


        inviteType = dictionary["type"] as? String
        inviteId = dictionary["complimentId"] as? String
        status = dictionary["status"] as? Bool
        timeStamp = dictionary["timeStamp"] as? Int

        sender = dictionary["fromUser"] as? User

        print("sender.name: \(sender!.firstName), \(sender!.birthday), \(String(describing: sender?.occupation))")

    }//end didSet

}//end var
```

Here is my User model:

```
struct User {

    let uid: String
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let profilePictureURL: String

    var occupation: String?

    let birthday: String
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let gender: String
    let discoverable: Bool
    let online: Bool

    let discoveryPrefs: [String : Any]

    var profileImages = [String]()

    init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {

        self.uid = uid
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
        self.profilePictureURL = dictionary["profilePictureURL"] as? String ?? ""

        self.occupation = dictionary["occupation"] as? String ?? ""

        self.birthday = dictionary["birthday"] as? String ?? ""
        self.firstName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
        self.lastName = dictionary["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
        self.gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String ?? ""
        self.discoverable = dictionary["discoverable"] as? Bool ?? false
        self.online = dictionary["online"] as? Bool ?? false

        self.discoveryPrefs = dictionary["discoveryPrefs"] as? [String : Any] ?? [String : Any]()
        self.profileImages = dictionary["profileImages"] as! [String]


    }//end init

}//end class
```

And this is where I build my User object:

```
func getUserInfo(forUserId forId: String, handler: @escaping (User) -> ()) {

        REF_USERS.child(forId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            //handle snapshot code here...

            var occupa: String?

            if let occupation = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "occupation").value as? String {
                occupa = occupation
            } else {
                occupa = ""
            }



            let dictionary: [String : Any] = ["uid": uid, "name": name, "email": email, "profilePictureURL": profilePictureURL, "birthday": birthday, "firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "gender": gender, "discoverable": discoverable, "online": online, "discoveryPrefs": discoveryPrefs, "profileImages": profileImages!, "occupation": occupa!]

            let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)

            handler(user)
        }, withCancel: { (error) in
            print(error)
        })


    }//end func
```

Comment: because sender?.occupation is optional, you can either force unwrap or set empty sting like sender?.occupation ?? ""

Comment: `String(describing:)` is almost *never* what you really want if the compiler suggests it to silence a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the line where you're printing the values, you'll notice that you're trying to print the value of an optional.

```
print("sender.name: \(sender!.firstName), \(sender!.birthday), \(String(describing: sender?.occupation))")
```

In the last part, you haven't unwrapped the `sender` which is still an optional and the attribute variable `occupation` is also an optional. Replace the last part with

```
print(sender?.occupation ?? "")
```

Or

```
if let occupation = sender?.occupation {
    print(occupation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `var occupation: String?` is Optional.
`String(describing:object)` is the same as `"\(object)"`, if the object is `Optional` type the text will be wrapped by `Optional()`. You have to unwrap it to get rid of it.